# How can I generate selections for a dropdown menu based on values in my database?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, drop-down-menu, mysqli

Here's a pic of what i'm trying to achieve

http://oi60.tinypic.com/b9gf20.jpg

Heres all my code...

### PHP FILE: contact_form.php

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME', 'xxx');
define('DB_USER', 'xxx');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxx');
define('DB_HOST', 'xxx');

$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if(!$connection){
    die('Database connection failed: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db($connection, DB_NAME);

if(!$db_selected){
    die('Can\'t use ' .DB_NAME . ' : ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo 'Connected successfully';

if (isset($_POST['itemname'])){
    $itm = $_POST['itemname'];
}else{
    $itm = '';
}    

if($_POST['mile']){
    $mi = $_POST['mile'];
}else{
    echo "Miles not received";
    exit;
}

if($_POST['email']){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
}else{
    echo "email not received";
    exit;
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO seguin_orders (itemname, mile, email) VALUES ('$itm', '$mi', '$email')";
if (!mysqli_query($connection, $sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_connect_error($connection));
}
```

### CONACT FORM: formz.php

```
<html>
<header>



</header>

<body>

<form action="/demoform/contact_form.php" class="well" id="contactForm" method="post" name="sendMsg" novalidate="">

<big>LOAD PAST ORDERS:</big>
<select id="extrafield1" name="extrafield1">
<option value="">Please select...</option>
</select>

</br>

<input type="text" required id="mile" name="mile" placeholder="Miles"/>

</br>

<input id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required="" type="text" value="demo@gmail.com" readonly="readonly"/>

</br>

<input id="name" name="itemname" placeholder="ITEM NAME 1" required="" type="text" />

</br>

<input type="reset" value="Reset" />


<button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>


</form>


</body>


</html>
```

Much thanks and appreciation for any time and help with this thanks.

Comment: You have to detect when someone finishes typing in their email, make a query on the database with this value, and within a loop echo out the <select> <options> with the values from the matched query.

Comment: no ones typing in there email...the value is already loaded and populated with a users email address when there logged in

Comment: So within the form echo out the options with the values taken from that particular column in each row (the looping part) based on the query using their email.

Comment: I tried this ...not working... http://codeviewer.org/view/code:49c5

Comment: Echo out the entire thing, including the option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form>
    <?php 
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        {
         echo '<option value =" ' . $row['column'] . ' ">' . $row['column'] . '</option>';
        };
    ?>
 </form>
```

Comment: cant get it to work my friend...how would i adapt this to my code?

Answer (score 0):

When you click select ,then send a ajax request to another php script to select database about the columns you want;then change it;like this:

```
 <input name="email" />
 <select onclick="ajaxFunc();" name="sel">
 </select>
 <script>
 function ajaxFunc(){
 var mail = $("input[name='email']").val();
 $.post('anotherFile.php',{mail:mail},function(e){
 $("select[name='sel']").append(e);
 });
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: im just trying to show a column's values from my database as a list of selections for my drop down